# How to make a JAVA applet Autorun?

Tags: java, autorun

I have a JAVA project that updates a database.

But I have to manually run the project so the database becomes updated.
And when I forget, it's just a pain in the ass, so my boss comes to me and starts to say a lot of things.

I want to export a .jar file that runs when Windows starts, checks if the database is updated, and, if not, update it.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you are not running in a browser, then you don't need an applet.

Then there are two ways to do this:

- make a `.bat` file that calls `java -jar \path\to\your\jar\file.jar` and place it in `Start Menu > Programs > Startup` (which is actually `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`
- install as service (but this is rather complicated)